# Extracting data from a file with a regular expression in sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

How can I use sed to extract `f607b9ab-1452-4758-b047-6b620591211b` by using `cmrepo-222-02` as my reference?

```
["+--------------------------------------+---------------+----------+------+-------------+", "| ID                                   | Name          | Status   | Size | Attached to |", "+--------------------------------------+---------------+----------+------+-------------+", "| f607b9ab-1452-4758-b047-6b620591211b | cmrepo-222-02 | creating |    1 |             |", "| 5e9b27fd-46b4-4950-9dc1-a838be21aff7 | cmrepo-222-01 | creating |    1 |             |", "+--------------------------------------+---------------+----------+------+-------------+"]
```

Comment: SInce you didn't use a code block, the formatting of your input document is hard to decipher, which makes the question even harder to answer. But you need to be clearer about your requirements. Is there just one string like this you want to extract, or are there many? What is known in advance about the structure of the input file? Is it always the same number of lines, etc.? Describe your problem more explicitly, or it is very hard to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ ref=cmrepo-222-02
$ sed "s/.* \([[:alnum:]-]\+\).*$ref.*/\1/" input_file
f607b9ab-1452-4758-b047-6b620591211b
```

Comment: 100% WORKING!!!

Comment: 100% Thank you so very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a json array of strings representing the lines of the output (intended for human consumption, not for post-processing) of some SQL query. So you could use `jq` to decode the `json` and `awk` to attempt to extract data from that formatted table.

```
<that-file jq -r '.[]' - |
  awk -F '[[:space:]]*[|][[:space:]]*' '$3 == "cmrepo-222-02" {print $2}'
```

But best would be to do the right SQL query in the first place.